# How to extract location attributes using Geocoder?

Tags: android, setlocale

When I try to get default locale it returns "zz_ZZ":

countryCode: "ZZ"
languageCode: "zz"

Code is:

```
private String getAddressFromLocation(Location location) {

    Geocoder geoCoder = new Geocoder(this.getApplicationContext(), Locale.getDefault());
    List<Address> matches = null;
    try {
        matches = geoCoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), 1);
        Address bestMatch = (matches.isEmpty() ? null : matches.get(0) );

        if (bestMatch != null){
            String fullAddress = bestMatch.getAddressLine(0);
            for (int i = 1; i <= bestMatch.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){
                fullAddress += ", " + bestMatch.getAddressLine(i);
            }
            return fullAddress;
        }else{
            return Constants.EMPTY_STRING;
        }

    } catch (IOException e) {
        ACRA.getErrorReporter().handleSilentException(new MyGeoLocationAddressException(TAG + " ERROR CREATING ADDRESS - " + e.getMessage()));
        return Constants.EMPTY_STRING;
    }
}
```

Do I need to setDefaultLocale? What does ZZ_zz mean?

Second problem is:

If I use the "ZZ_zz" default locale, I don't get any address but if I use:

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

I get the exact address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ZZ_zz` is the identifier for the *Accented English* locale and is mostly used for finding missing translations in your app.

I don't think there's a best practice on how to handle accented english, but treating it as english would probably be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

You must handle locations in this way, check the scenario when no address is returned

```
List<Address> addresses = null;

    try {
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                location.getLatitude(),
                location.getLongitude(),
                // In this sample, get just a single address.
                1);
    } catch (IOException ioException) {
        // Catch network or other I/O problems.
        errorMessage = getString(R.string.service_not_available);
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage, ioException);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
        // Catch invalid latitude or longitude values.
        errorMessage = getString(R.string.invalid_lat_long_used);
        Log.e(TAG, errorMessage + ". " +
                "Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() +
                ", Longitude = " +
                location.getLongitude(), illegalArgumentException);
    }

    // Handle case where no address was found.
    if (addresses == null || addresses.size()  == 0) {
        if (errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
            errorMessage = getString(R.string.no_address_found);
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
        }
        deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.FAILURE_RESULT, errorMessage);
    } else {
        Address address = addresses.get(0);
        ArrayList<String> addressFragments = new ArrayList<String>();

        // Fetch the address lines using getAddressLine,
        // join them, and send them to the thread.
        for(int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
            addressFragments.add(address.getAddressLine(i));
        }
        Log.i(TAG, getString(R.string.address_found));
        deliverResultToReceiver(Constants.SUCCESS_RESULT,
                TextUtils.join(System.getProperty("line.separator"),
                        addressFragments));
    }
}
```